# Enviar requisição sincrona com ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou usando Ajax para enviar dados via POST, o "problema" é que não quero que seja enviado de forma assincrona no background, gostaria de enviar com o mesmo comportamento de um submit de formulário, adicionei a opçao: `async:false`, mas não mudou nada, como proceder?

Atualização:
Não é viável criar um formulário normal e "injetar" os parametros, pois são arrays e gerados no javascript.

Comment: Então por quê já não traz esse conteúdo na própria resposta que fornece a página? Não existe motivos de fazer uma requisição síncrona com JS.

Comment: Meio sem sentido isto, não?

Comment: Não entendi, anderson, os parametros são gerados no javascript e enviados...

Comment: e como o parametro é um array, seria inviável fazer "uma gambiarra" e injetar esses dados num formulário genérico

Comment: cara é o seguinte, as versões mais novas do Jquery não possuem `async: false`

Comment: Então não existe uma forma de se fazer? pelo menos não com ajax?

Comment: Exatamente, acompanha aqui http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/